# Django JSON or TASTYPIE for Android App

Tags: android, python, django, json

I am building a small business site (Django framework) which will be later available in Android based phones. I face uncertainity w.r.t following:

1. Should I used Django based API like Tastypie to expose the dataset to Phones or Django VIEWS returning result in JSON format and call the URI. What is Industry best practice?
2. I tried using Tastypie, but I was unable to put business logic in ModelsResource Class. I find VIEWS better position to do the same. AM I RIGHT/WRONG/Missing something ?
3. Is it possible to call VIEWS inside API Resource?

Thank you

Comment: You can do business logic in a tastypie resource. Have a look at the `full_hydrate(self, bundle)` method which is passed the final "bundle" before serving a result, allowing you an opportunity to modify the object. Just make sure `return bundle` when you are done. Or, just read up on the `dehydrate` / `hydrate` cycles altogether. :)

Comment: Can you point out what are disadvantages in using Django based view return JSON instead of tastypie api...